# On radio button click text box should display

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi i am working on react and i am facing some issues regarding the radio button.I have case like Yes or No where when ever user say Yes i have to show the text box and when he say No i have to hide the text box.

so can any one give me the suggestion that how i can perform this task.
I am using Ant design to show the radio button.

```js
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator("isBranchAvailable", {
            initialValue: this.props.firmDetails.isBranchAvailable,
          })(
              <Radio.Group>
                <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
                <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
              </Radio.Group>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
```

Comment: use onChange event on RadioGroup and use setState to do required output

Comment: and conditional rendering

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion it help to me. But how you can hold state to the updated value when you work on multi page application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `antd` library. You should also incorporate `component-state` to help toggle the display of the `Input`, we'll call this `showTextBox`.

In your code, set up an event-listener and handler for changes to the `Radio.Group` selection.

Then in the event-handler simply verify if the selected item has a value of 1 with a `===` check. The evaluated result will be used to update the state.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-oolj3

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Radio, Input } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showTextBox: false
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      showTextBox: e.target.value === 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { showTextBox } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form.Item>
          <Radio.Group onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
            <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
            <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
          {showTextBox && <Input placeholder="whatsup" />}
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: it is working for me but now when say Yes and pass value to input box and  move back and forth the state again set to false because of that the text box get hide. Is there any way that i can hold my state on multi page application

Comment: You would have to integrate some type of global-state manager like Redux to help persist that data or you can use local-storage to preserve that data. Would either sound good to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Radio, Input } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

class Autocomplete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Form layout="inline">
        <Form.Item>
          <Radio.Group
            name={"rb1"}
            onChange={e =>
              this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
              })
            }
          >
            <Radio value={true}>Yes</Radio>
            <Radio value={false}>No</Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        </Form.Item>
        {this.state.rb1 ? (
          <Form.Item>
            <Input placeholder="placeholder" allowClear />
          </Form.Item>
        ) : null}
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
const MyForm = Form.create()(Autocomplete);
export default MyForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Radio, Input } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showTextBox: false
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    if(e.target.value===1){
      this.setState({showTextBox:true})
    }
    else{
      this.setState({showTextBox:false})
    }

  };

  render() {
    const { showTextBox } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form.Item>
          <Radio.Group onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
            <Radio value={1}>yes</Radio>
            <Radio value={2}>no</Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
          {showTextBox && <Input placeholder="whatsup" />}
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```